# weird dataset in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, dataset

I have built a dataset named `Transaction_Time`.

I called it on `Page_Load`

```
Transaction_Time tranTme = new Transaction_Time();
```

put it in the session.

```
Session["Transaction"] = tranTme;
```

Then I call that session and cast to dataset.

```
DataSet dstTranTime = (DataSet)Session["Transaction"];
```

I got the following error.

Unable to cast object of type 'Transaction_Time' to type 'System.Data.DataSet'.

```
[InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'Transaction_Time' to type 'System.Data.DataSet'.]
   Transaction_Time.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\William29_11_2010\Transaction_Time.aspx.cs:47
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

It is OK for some other pages. But for some page, it doesn't.

Is it something wrong that I do or.. ???

Comment: When you say you've "built a dataset named Transaction_Time", does this `Transaction_Time` class actually derive from the `DataSet` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may have two classes called Transaction_Time. If you have created a class called Transaction_Time and derived it from DataSet AND you have a class called Transaction_Time that is derived from, say, Page. Then the compiler may be confused about which you mean and you may occasionally be storing the page Transaction_Time rather than the DataSet Transaction_Time.

Be explicit when creating the Transaction_Time class and use the fully qualified name OR rename one of your classes so that the name is not ambiguous. That should solve your problem (assuming my assumptions are correct).

Comment: Going by what you said "I have built a dataset named Transaction_Time." - I'm assuming that means you have a "class Transaction_Time : DataSet" somewhere in your code. The exception also shows that your page or control is called "Transaction_Time".

Comment: If you have not declared a class called "Transaction_Time" that it is derived from then it is invalid to call "new Transaction_Time()" and expect a DataSet. However, since you said you have this problem on some pages and not others I'm guessing you must also have a classed called Transaction_Time derived from DataSet.

Comment: based on his description he used Visual Studio to create a strongly typed Dataset without having to use the command line tools (Add New Item, DataSet, then drag tables to it to create a strongly typed dataset). You are correct in that this class that is created inherits from DataSet.

Answer (score 3):

You put in typeof(Transaction_Time) and try to get out typeof(DataSet). this will fail until
Transaction_Time is not derived from DataSet. Try to read Transaction_Time instead of DataSet.

```
   Transaction_Time tranTme = new Transaction_Time(); 
   ....
   Session["Transaction"] = tranTme; 
   ....
   Transaction_Time dstTranTime = Session["Transaction"] as Transaction_Time; 

   if (dstTranTime == null)
       System.Dignostics.Trace.WriteLine("Ups! Expecting Transaction_Time, but got {0}", Session["Transaction"] );
```